# how hibernate manage serialization id while saving/fetching object in/from DB

Tags: java, database, hibernate, serialization

As per my understanding to manage consistency serialization algo maintain one serialization id as `private static final long serialVersionUID = 3170588813843556321L;` in class while saving/fetching object from stream. and that id will be saved in that file/stream.

But with DB while we are NOT saving this in DB at all, so how hibernate check consistency during deserialization and throw `java.io.InvalidClassException`.

Please correct me if i am wrong at my understanding....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hibernate does not use serialization to store your classes into the database. it works by way of [object relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and (simplistically) maps every attribute of your object to a column in a table.
only if you have specific types of attributes (say `public Image getImage()`) will it store "real" binary - it might map this attribute to a blob to use serialization/deserialization to store/load the image attribute of your mapped class.

checking for data consistency in hibernate is done either via explicit locking (it locks the rows that make up your entity as long as your entity is in use) or via [optimistic locking](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/versioning-optimistic-locking-in-hibernate/) - where it will add a "version" field to your entity, update it every time you modify the entity, and use sql of the form `"update table set ... where version=:myVersion"` to ensure that no 2 processes modify the same entity at the same time.

Comment: i m not talking about the lock management of hibernate which is used basically in concurrent access/modification, this is about `serialVersionUID` which we have to maintain in each DTO while using Hibernate.
.............
So if hibernate does not care about Serialization then why this is mandatory to implement `java.io.Serializable` for DTO.

Comment: DTOs and hibernate (JPA) classes dont have to be the same thing. DTOs are usually passed around, sometimes sent remotely, and so must be serializable. JPA entities are just stored to DB and read back from it (of course the same class can be both). also - its _RECOMMENDED_ you set an explicit serial UID. you dont have to.